Error serving sites locally with Laravel Valet
This issue is on Apple Sonoma 14.4.1.
Hi All. I have an issue serving sites locally (on .test) that I have been struggling with for days at this point. Anyone who could help would be amazing at this point.
The problem: Local sites (ie. site.test) generate a 502 error in the browser. I CAN successfully ping sites from the CL but they will not load in the browser. It seems the errors are pointing to an issue with valet.sock. I see a symbolic link for it in /valet/valet.sock but it points to nowhere.
NOTE: I installed Powershell for Mac and Parallels which I believe is where the problem originated. I have since uninstalled both as well as a complete reinstall of Valet (and an OS update to Sonoma 14.4.1). Valet has been working perfect for several years before this.
nginx-error.log shows this error:
2024/04/05 10:09:36 [crit] 7683#0: *1 connect() to unix:/Users/joeconlin/.config/valet/valet.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/Users/joeconlin/.config/valet/valet.sock:", host: "joeconlin.test"

dnsmasq --no-daemon returns:
dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 127.0.0.1: Permission denied

scutil --dns returns:
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : localdomain
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  nameserver[1] : 4.2.2.2
  nameserver[2] : 8.8.8.8
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00030002 (Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address)

resolver #2
  domain   : local
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300000

resolver #3
  domain   : 254.169.in-addr.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300200

resolver #4
  domain   : 8.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300400

resolver #5
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300600

resolver #6
  domain   : a.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 300800

resolver #7
  domain   : b.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : 0x00000000 (Not Reachable)
  order    : 301000

resolver #8
  domain   : test
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00030002 (Reachable,Local Address,Directly Reachable Address)

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : localdomain
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  nameserver[1] : 4.2.2.2
  nameserver[2] : 8.8.8.8
  if_index : 9 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)

resolver #2
  nameserver[0] : fd00:976a::9
  nameserver[1] : fd00:976a::10
  if_index : 21 (ipsec0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request AAAA records
  reach    : 0x00000002 (Reachable)

/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq-valet.conf contents:
address=/.test/127.0.0.1 
listen-address=127.0.0.1

My hosts file:
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1         localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
# fe80::1%lo0     localhost

Any thoughts?
NOTE: I installed Powershell for Mac and Parallels which I believe is where the problem originated. I have since uninstalled both and well as a complete reinstall of Valet (and an OS update to Sonoma 14.4.1).
